# Line ending ^I0 in unix file

Tags: unix

I am trying to understand the difference between this windows line ending file:

```
cmccabe@DTV-A5211QLM:~/Desktop/bed$ head -10 xgen_baits.bed | cat -et
chr1^I955542^I955662^IAGRN_70^I0^I+^M$
chr1^I955643^I955763^IAGRN_71^I0^I+^M$
chr1^I957570^I957690^IAGRN_72^I0^I+^M$
```

and this unix file:

```
cmccabe@DTV-A5211QLM:~/Desktop/bed$ head -10 xgen_baits_unix.bed | cat -et
chr1^I955542^I955662^IAGRN_70^I0^I+$
chr1^I955643^I955763^IAGRN_71^I0^I+$
chr1^I957570^I957690^IAGRN_72^I0^I+$
```

the `^I` symbol is tab the `$` symbol is newline,  but what is the `^I0`?  Thank you :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the full symbol is just `^I`, and what is near is a zero. So your line would be something like this:

```
chr1<tab>955542<tab>955662<tab>AGRN_70<tab>0<tab>+$
```